# Angular2, how to initialize a component class(child) when extends a parent class?

Tags: inheritance, angular

For example, I have a component and a class named ChildComponent class extends from paren class. How can I initialize the ChildComponent class? In angular2, when the component was used in html, it will automatically call ChildComponent class, then what happened during it comes to `super(param1, param2);` ? Can anyone give an example to explain it?

```
class ChildComponent extends Parent {
   constructor(param1: string, param2: string){
      super(param1, param2);
   };
}

class Parent {
   constructor(param1: string, param2: string){};
}
```

Comment: So what is the actual question? What does happen when `super(param1, param2);` is called? The `constructor` of `Parent` is called. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean, like in Java, we use ChildComponent child = new ChildComponent(param1, param2) to initialize an object. But in angular2, I don't know how to initialize an object? Or how to initialize the value to the class members/properties param1 and param2.?

Comment: You class is named `ChildComponent`. If it is a component, you don't initialize them yourself as Thierry said.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't initialize components by yourself with Angular2. The latter manages them by its own. That's why the parameter you provide into component constructor are injected by the framework. You're free then to call the super contructor if you want.

**Edit**

With TypeScript, you can leverage types of constructor parameters. For example to inject an Http instance:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {}
}
```

You need to configure a provider to allow Angular2 to instantiate the element to inject. For Http:

```
bootstrap(MyComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Comment: I haven't used inject stuff before, could you please show me an example of code about how does the parameter injected by the framework?

Comment: Thanks @Thierry Templier. Here Http class is the one that already defined by angular2, but in my example above, Parent class is the one I created by myself. Does it work the same way? Or can you please show me how to do with my above example?